# Control F with Equal Sign in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to use Control+F in my excel workbook but I have an issue. I have 2 sheets that I compare. Sheet A has a record of all my logs and Sheet B has my logs.

When I input the records into Sheet A I simply use `= [cell value]` from Sheet B. I do this because it's much quicker to use the equal sign then to retype all the information from Sheet B.

However, I can't use the Control+F function to look up my records in Sheet A. Sheet A cell B5 shows "360 LLC" the cell value is `='Sheet B'!E10`. So when I type `'Sheet B'!E10` in the Control+F pop-menu I get the record "360 LLC"

Is there a way I can use Control+F to look up "360 LLC" by typing in the pop-up menu `360 LLC` instead of `'Sheet B'!E10`?

Thanks.

Comment: In the Find and Replace Dialog, under Options, Look in Values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have the Find box up, select `Values` for the `Look in:`  field.  If you don't see these selections, click `Options`.

[image: Control F options]

Comment: I never knew about this "Look in" option. This is perfect, thanks!

Comment: Is there a way I can lock the "Lock in" to stay on "Values"? I closed my workbook and opened to test it and it reverts back to "Formulas".

Comment: I think the only way to do this is with an Auto_Open macro.  However, I've never tried that.